# While merging in Oracle 11g, I want to delete destination row that is not matching with source

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-merge

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM SOURCE;

 MEMBER_ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  RANK
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 Abel       Wolf       Gold
         2 Clarita    Franco     Platinum
         3 Darryl     Giles      Silver
         4 Dorthea    Suarez     Silver
         5 Katrina    Wheeler    Silver
         6 Lilian     Garza      Silver
         7 Ossie      Summers    Gold
         8 Paige      Mcfarland  Platinum
         9 Ronna      Britt      Platinum
        10 Tressie    Short      Bronze

10 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT * FROM DESTINATION;

 MEMBER_ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  RANK
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 Abel       Wolf       Silver
         2 Clarita    Franco     Platinum
         3 Darryl     Giles      Bronze
         4 Dorthea    Gate       Gold
         5 Katrina    Wheeler    Silver
         6 Lilian     Stark      Silver
        11 Chris      Well       Silver

7 rows selected.
```

When I am trying to execute the below query, it is getting executed but not record 11 is getting deleted from destination table:

```
MERGE INTO DESTINATION D
USING SOURCE S
ON (D.MEMBER_ID = S.MEMBER_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
     SET D.FIRST_NAME = S.FIRST_NAME,
         D.LAST_NAME  = S.LAST_NAME,
         D.RANK       = S.RANK 
  DELETE
   WHERE D.MEMBER_ID <> S.MEMBER_ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (D.MEMBER_ID, D.FIRST_NAME, D.LAST_NAME, D.RANK)
  VALUES
    (S.MEMBER_ID, S.FIRST_NAME, S.LAST_NAME, S.RANK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the current logic uses `INNER JOIN` implicitly, and `MEMBER_ID = 11` doesn't exist within the table `SOURCE`, so this values does not incur the `MATCHED` case, thus never been deleted.

You can use an `OUTER JOIN` such as `FULL JOIN` as below

```
MERGE INTO DESTINATION D
USING (SELECT NVL(S.MEMBER_ID,D.MEMBER_ID) AS MEMBER_ID,S.FIRST_NAME, S.LAST_NAME, S.RANK 
         FROM DESTINATION D
         FULL JOIN SOURCE S
           ON S.MEMBER_ID = D.MEMBER_ID) S
   ON (NVL(S.MEMBER_ID,D.MEMBER_ID) = D.MEMBER_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
     SET D.FIRST_NAME = S.FIRST_NAME,
         D.LAST_NAME  = S.LAST_NAME,
         D.RANK       = S.RANK 
  DELETE
   WHERE S.FIRST_NAME IS NULL
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (D.MEMBER_ID, D.FIRST_NAME, D.LAST_NAME, D.RANK)
  VALUES
    (S.MEMBER_ID, S.FIRST_NAME, S.LAST_NAME, S.RANK);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cd336e489d7ed9b2313163b1d15bae66)</kbd>